# Vb.net on running shows updation exception

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-2.0

```
 I've a website in vb.net. While running the website i get the following error:
```

**"Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype."**

```
 My DB connection.inc file looks as follows:
```

Dim strDataSource As String
Dim cnnCRM As ADODB.Connection

I've tried giving the record set object all the properties it required. Still the same error. Can anybody tell me how i can get rid of this error?.....

---

DB has full permissions. This error happened when i called a function.My code is shown below:

<%=(funcGetMaxDate(rstAWCList.Fields("TOMONTH").Value, rstAWCList.Fields("TOYEAR").Value) & "/" & IIF(IsDBNull(rstAWCList.Fields.Item("TOMONTH").Value), Nothing, rstAWCList.Fields.Item("TOMONTH").Value) & "/" & IIF(IsDBNull(rstAWCList.Fields.Item("TOYEAR").Value), Nothing, rstAWCList.Fields.Item("TOYEAR").Value))%>

The definiton works perfectly. The function definition is as follows:

Function funcGetMaxDate(ByRef prmMonth As String, ByRef prmYear As String) As String
    Dim intPrmMonth As Integer
    intPrmMonth =prmMonth 
    Dim iDate As String

```
Select Case intPrmMonth
    Case 1
        iDate = 31
    Case 2
        iDate = CheckMaxDateFebruary(prmYear)
    Case 3
        iDate = 31
    Case 4
        iDate = 30
    Case 5
        iDate = 31
    Case 6
        iDate = 30
    Case 7
        iDate = 31
    Case 8
        iDate = 31
    Case 9
        iDate = 30
    Case 10
        iDate = 31
    Case 11
        iDate = 30
    Case 12
        iDate = 31
    Case Else
        iDate = 0
End Select  
funcGetMaxDate = iDate
```

End Function

When the ctrl reaches back the calling function this exception occurs.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like you need to specify cursor information such as `adOpenDynamic` or `adOpenStatic` as well as lock information such as `adLockOptimistic`

```
RS.Open(..., Con, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

Also, you'll find that most people in the .Net world have moved away from ADODB and use either the native SqlClient or native OLEDB providers.

Comment: I got same solution and it worked for me. 
Any way Thanks for your answer... Chris

Answer (score 0):

Does the user that the website is running as have permission to modify that MDB file? If the database is either read-only or only has NTFS read permissions, it's possible that it may report this error.

Comment: Hi,
    I've edited the question with your reply as well as my code. plz check the question once again................